# SPARQL - Query any information of things in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to find description of specific things without knowing whether the things are Thing, Person, Place, Location, etc.
I wonder If I am able to do so in DBpedia?
Eg:

- **Search:** Manchester United.
  **Query Result:** Manchester United Football Club, commonly known as Man. *And so on....*
- **Search:** Maldives.
  **Query Result:** The Maldives is a tropical nation in the Indian Ocean composed of 26 ring-shaped atolls. *And so on....*

Comment: You never have to know the type. You just have to know the URI. You could also try to use the `rdfs:label`, but different entities can have the same label, thus, it's not a unique identifier in general compared to a URI.

Comment: If I use urls, is there any ways to get a url of specific thing? If no, than rdfs:label is my posible way

Comment: It sounds like you basically have a string is input, e.g. "Manchester United". the only way then is to search for resources having this string in some property that declares the human readable name of the resource, e.g. via `rdfs:label` property. But, as I said, multiple URIs can have the same label indeed, e.g. persons, places etc. For label based lookup, either use exact match, i.e. `?s rdfs:label "Manchester United"@en .` or something with `regex` function (or in the case of DBpedia, `bif:contains`

Comment: 1) `?s rdfs:label "Manchester United"@en .` or 2) `?s rdfs:label ?l . filter(langmatches(lang(?l), 'en') && regex(str(?l), 'Manchester United', 'i')) ` or 3) `?s rdfs:label ?l . filter(langmatches(lang(?l), 'en')) ?l bif:contains "'Manchester United'" .`

Comment: I'll try to do it, really big thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check out the [Faceted Browser](http://dbpedia.org/fct/), a feature of Virtuoso, which powers the public DBpedia endpoints.

1. [Search on "Manchester United".](http://dbpedia.org/fct/facet.vsp?qxml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20%3F%3E%3Cquery%20inference%3D%22%22%20same-as%3D%22%22%20view3%3D%22%22%20s-term%3D%22%22%20c-term%3D%22%22%20agg%3D%22%22%3E%3Ctext%3EManchester%20United%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Cview%20type%3D%22text-d%22%20limit%3D%2220%22%20offset%3D%22%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fquery%3E)
2. Have an idea what type the entity you're looking for is?  [Click "Type" in the right-hand link list.](http://dbpedia.org/fct/facet.vsp?qxml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20%3F%3E%3Cquery%20inference%3D%22%22%20same-as%3D%22%22%20view3%3D%22%22%20s-term%3D%22%22%20c-term%3D%22%22%20agg%3D%22%22%3E%3Ctext%3EManchester%20United%3C%2Ftext%3E%3Cview%20type%3D%22classes%22%20limit%3D%2220%22%20offset%3D%220%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fquery%3E)
3. Explore as you will...  Eventually you'll find a page that seems useful.

   a. Want to save that page for later?  Click "Permalink" and copy the full link from the address box -- or just right-click "Permalink" and choose "copy link" from the contextual menu -- or bookmark the "Permalink".

   b. Want to edit that query to build your own?  Try "View query as SPARQL".

Comment: However, we cannot search label by regex or something like "LIKE %%" in SQL, right?

Comment: I guess you haven't looked at [the SPARQL spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), or you just overlooked [REGEX](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex) and various related functions and keywords...

Comment: You may also find exploring the [drag-and-drop graphical iSPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/) query builder helpful...